# Android In-App Billing V3 How to reset android.test.refunded SKU

Tags: android, testing, in-app-billing

I have in-app billing v3 working fine using the Trivial Drive Sample code, except integrated into my own app, and ran all the static tests, and those ran fine also.  However, the one static test SKU, "android.text.refunded", after running that test, it will not go away now.  I have tried consuming it with mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener), like all the others and it does not get consumed and keeps coming back like a mother-in-law at Christmas...

Is there some way to reset it in the Developers Console?  Not sure if this will ever go away.
BING!